# Django Error : 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a simple form, but somehow everytime I push the enter button, this error shows up? so what did I do wrong?

This is my views :

```
@login_required
def voted(response):
    user = Userdata.objects.get(id=response.user.id)  # get the username
    if user.is_voted == True:
        return render(response, 'Main/voting.html', {'calon' : Voting.objects.order_by('id'), 'hasil' : 'You Have Voted'})
    if response.method == 'POST':
        id = int(response.POST.get['idcalon'])
        calon2 = Voting.objects.get(id = id)  # get user selection in html
        user.is_voted = True
        calon2.voters += 1
        user.save()
        calon2.save()
    return render(response, 'Main/voting.html', {'calon' : Voting.objects.order_by('id')})  # balik ke sendiri
```

This is the Html :

```
<form method="POST">
                      {% if calon %}
                          {% for para in calon %}
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small" style="line-height: 1.5rem;">
                        <input type="radio" id="huey" name="idcalon" value="{{ forloop.counter }}" checked>
                                <label for="huey">{{ para.name }}</label>  </div>
                          {% endfor %}
                      {% else %}
                      {% endif %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-10">{% csrf_token %}
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vote Now</button></div>
                    </div>
</form>
```

My guest is at the value in the HTML, but I personally don't know how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: It shoudl be ***`response.POST.get('idcalon')`***  instead of `response.POST.get['idcalon']`

Answer (score 2):

The **`.get()`** is a method and you should've call it with using *paranthesis* as,

```
response.POST.get('idcalon')
```

You can also retrieve the desired value from `request.POST` by

```
response.POST['idcalon']
```